Can I write a specific rule about how git should handle a specific commonly occurring merge conflict in a specific file?
I have an Obsidian vault under version control, and one of the plugins synchronises with an external source, updating a timestamp in the config file.
I switch between two separate user accounts for security reasons, so when I pull the repo, I almost always have conflicts in that file.
{
  "dateHighlightedFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
  ...
  "filter": "ALL",
<<<<<<< HEAD
  "syncAt": "2024-07-21T22:24:25",
=======
  "syncAt": "2024-07-22T09:35:14",
>>>>>>> 6630c5d461bcb5c4950e2694a67c60aee57acc7d
  ...
}

In this case, I always want to use the latest timestamp. There is no guarantee which file is the most current, if it's the local or the remote.
Is there a way I can configure this for git?
I imagine that it should be possible to run a shell script on a specific hook. If the script exits with a zero exit code, it was able to handle the merge successfully, and git would create the merge. On a non-zero, git would fallback to normal merge behaviour, requiring user interaction for conflict resolution.
But that's just my idea of one possible approach to a solution. Maybe there are other better solutions?
p.s. I seem to recall that NPM was able to setup something specifically for package-lock.json. So unless I am mistaken about this, it should be technically possible.

Take a look at git help rerere. Might be able to solve the problem (I have never used it so don't really know if it can pull it off, though).

if its realy only one file you might consider just restoring it before pulling, e.g git restore my_file

@eftshift0 I believe that rerere doesn't solve my problem. It records a resolution, so e.g. you've made a merge, and later converts it to a rebase, it can remember how each conflict was resolved In this case, the conflicts are different, i.e. different timestamps. And you can never be sure which version is the current, so it requires some "domain specific" logic to handle

@johnSmith I can't be sure if the local or remote is the most current. Updated the question to make this explicit.

Maybe a custom merge driver?

You can write a custom merge driver.
Suppose we have a merge driver /usr/bin/latest.py. Remember to make it executable if not on Windows.
In gitconfig:
[merge."latest"]
        name = "choose the latest timestamp"
        driver = /usr/bin/latest.py %O %A %B %L %P

In .gitattributes:
package-lock.json    merge=latest

Here is an crude implementation of latest.py in Python 3 (3.11.2 in my machine). If the shebang #!/usr/bin/env python does not work, try #!/usr/bin/env python3. You can write the merge driver in any programming language you like. It's a bit crude, as it's not really aware of JSON, and relies on the fact that ISO date/times sort alphabetically in this scenario.
It first creates two temporary files for the two branches being merged, and replace the syncAt line with the latest timestamp in both. After that it proceeds to call git merge-file -p passing these instead of the original. So for that particular line, git merge-file will see the same change, which will not conflict, but anything else will fallback to default git merge behaviour, making sure other conflicts will fail, requiring manual resolution.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import tempfile
import logging
import traceback

ancestor = sys.argv[1]
current = sys.argv[2]
other = sys.argv[3]
KEYWORD = '"syncAt":'

def merge_file(current, ancestor, other):
    cmd = 'git merge-file -p "%s" "%s" "%s"' % (current, ancestor, other)
    status, output = subprocess.getstatusoutput(cmd)
    return status, output

def get_syncat_line(p):
    syncat = ''
    with open(p) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip().startswith(KEYWORD):
                syncat = line
                break
    return syncat

def replace_syncat_line(p, replacement, output):
    with open(p) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip().startswith(KEYWORD):
                output.write(replacement)
                output.write("\n")
            else:
                output.write(line)
        output.write("\n")

def write_output_exit(output, status):
    with open(current, 'w') as f:
        f.write(output)
    sys.exit(status)

current_syncat = get_syncat_line(current)
other_syncat = get_syncat_line(other)
ancestor_syncat = get_syncat_line(ancestor)

def create_tmp_file():
    return tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete_on_close=False) 

if (current_syncat.strip() == other_syncat.strip()):
    status, output = merge_file(current, ancestor, other)
    write_output_exit(output, status)
else:
    try:
        if current_syncat.strip() > other_syncat.strip():
            latest_syncat = current_syncat.rstrip()
        else:
            latest_syncat = other_syncat.rstrip()

        with create_tmp_file() as tmp_current, \
            create_tmp_file() as tmp_other:

            replace_syncat_line(current, latest_syncat, tmp_current)
            replace_syncat_line(other, latest_syncat, tmp_other)
            tmp_current.close()
            tmp_other.close()
            status, output = merge_file(
                tmp_current.name, ancestor, tmp_other.name)

            write_output_exit(output, status)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
        status, output = merge_file(current, ancestor, other)
        write_output_exit(output, 1)


That is absolutely awesome, not only did you describe the mechanics that solve the problem, you provided a solution to my specific use case. <3 I will take that for a spin today.

python 2 or 3? Or doesn't matter? /usr/bin/env python fails on my setup, and I need to use /usr/bin/env python3. But AFAIK, many setups, python IS python 3? (I'm not a python dev - so not super knowledgeable on that topic)

@Pete I tested the script in Python 3 in git-bash. I've edited the answer to make it clear. Python 2 raises an exception on subprocess.getstatusoutput. Some other methods should be used instead. Besides, there might be other issues about string and bytes in Python 2.

Also: Friends don't let friends use Python 2 for anything that's not already a legacy project in 2024.

@JoachimSauer :D that was kindof the impression I had, but as mentioned - I'm not a python dev. But generally, for any reasonably current note I should be able to assume that any "modern" reference to "pyhton" including the executable, should mean python3?

Debian and Ubuntu have internally standardized to only reference the python2 and python3 binaries. However, since your assumption is perfectly reasonable there is a python-is-python3 package which basically creates the symlink. It's installed on all systems I care about, but I think that's a manual addition and not default.

@ElpieKay I'm a little surprised you've tested it. Didn't work at all for me, various reasons. First, when I tested it, there was still conflict markers. I fixed that but then saw other problems because it writes the result to the wrong file, e.g. git merge --abort doesn't work. It should overwrite arg[2], not arg[5]. Anyway, I created a solution that creates two temporary files that both has an updated syncAt before proceeding to git's own merge tool, removing the necessity of dealing with merge markers. I took the liberty of updating your answer with the new version.

I tested in git-bash on Windows. The driver solves only the conflict of "syncAt" and the others are left unchanged. git merge --abort can work in my test. As the doc says, it should write to argv[2] instead of argv[5]. argv[5] is the name(or path) of the merged file. Writing to it results in the same effect seemingly. But it most probably would have some issues. Glad your updated version can work. Thanks for making it better.

@ElpieKay - Glad to help to improve. I improved it a bit more, the TemporaryFile handles cleanup - so the file handling becomes much simpler. Anyway, I would not been able to solve it, had you not shown the way by incorporating git's buildin merge tool in the process.

@ElpieKay I also updated the code description - to reflect the changed implementation.
